# Can I use full features of WebAPi in ASP.NET Web Forms 4.5?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, webforms, async-await

I want to create some Web services but I Decided to use **WebAPI** as service framework instead of **WCF** so I have some questions:

1. Can I use **full features** of **WebAPi** in ASP.NET **Web Forms** 4.5 *without any problems*?
2. **WebForms** 4.5 works with **async await** programming?
3. **WebForms** 4.5 works with **HttpClient** Library and **Async programming** *without any problems or limitations*?
4. Is there any special *restrictions* with **WebAPI** in **ASP.NET WebForms 4.5**? (or visa versa)

*** If there is a limit, I'll be forced to use WCF  :(

Comment: A short answer: yes, you can. The next thing is how, [here is a good start](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheMagicOfUsingAsynchronousMethodsInASPNET45PlusAnImportantGotcha.aspx). You can use `HttpClient` whenever `WebClient` is used there.

Answer (score 5):

> 1) Can I use full features of WebAPi in ASP.NET Web Forms 4.5 without any problems?

Yes.

> 2) WebForms 4.5 works with async await programming?

Yes.

> 3) WebForms 4.5 works with HttpClient Library and Async programming without any problems or limitations?

Yes.

> 4) Is there any special restrictions with WebAPI in ASP.NET WebForms 4.5? (or visa versa)

No.